# How to Skip OncePerRequestFilter for specific endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on springboot application. Springboot version is 2.6.8. I am implementing spring security. I want to permit specific endpoints in the config class so that OncePerRequestFilter doesn't execute for these URLs. Here is my security config class

```
package com.springbootApp.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.springbootApp.filters.JwtRequestFilter;
import com.springbootApp.services.CustomUserDetailService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtFilter;

    @Autowired
    JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                  "/",
                  "/*.html",
                  "/*.svg",
                  "/*.png",
                  "/*.woff",
                  "/*.woff2",
                  "/*.svg",
                  "/*.jpg",
                  "/*.json",
                  "/favicon.ico",
                  "/*.json",
                  "/*.css",
                  "/*.js"
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/health/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

The APIs that I want to by pass are executed in the following controllers

HealthCheck controller

```
package com.springbootApp.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/health")
public class HealthCheck {
    
    @GetMapping("/check")
    public String healthCheck() {
        return "I am alive !!!!!";
    }

}
```

AuthController

```
package com.springbootApp.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.springbootApp.jwt.JwtUtil;
import com.springbootApp.models.JwtResponse;
import com.springbootApp.models.LoginRequest;
import com.springbootApp.models.UserRequestModel;
import com.springbootApp.services.CustomUserDetailService;
import com.springbootApp.services.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userSerivce;

    @PostMapping("login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest credentials) {
        try {
            this.authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword()));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unable to login.");
        }
        
        UserDetails userDetails = this.customUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(credentials.getUsername());
        final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt));
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public UserRequestModel addUser(@RequestBody UserRequestModel user) throws Exception {
        return this.userSerivce.addUser(user);
    }
}
```

[Update] Here's the JWTRequestFilter extended from OncePerRequestFilter

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtRequestFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        } else {
            logger.error("Invalid token header.");
            throw new OnlineStoreException("Invalid token!");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            } else {
                logger.error("Token is not valid.");
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I execute localhost:port/api/health/check or localhost:port/api/auth/login, I get an exception from doFilterInternal for Invalid Token. Since I specified these endpoints as permitall so filter should not be executed for these APIs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: whats the reason for not using the built in JWTFilter that comes with spring security and is documented in the docs?

Comment: You have to extend the OncePerRequestFilter class in order to skip specific endpoins.

Comment: I already extended this one. Updated the code.